# How to eliminate the html headline number?

Tags: org-mode

I am using org mode to write blogs, after publishing the project, I found the 
titles of the html has an line number before it. as below:

[image]

This is the original org file:
[image]

I don't like this. Is there a way to eliminate the number before title after exporting to html?

and this is my publish config:

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(("github-blog"
 :base-directory "/Users/blog/org/post/"
 :publishing-directory "/Users/blog/_posts/"
 :prepare-function nil
 :completion-function nil
 :exclude "*.html"
 :recursive nil
 :base-extension "org"
 :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
 :section-number nil
 :headline-levels nil
 :body-only t
 )))
```

Comment: Upvote when answer is good...

Answer (score 4):

file specific option: #+OPTIONS: num:nil

You may customize "org-export-with-section-numbers" to change the option globally, say: "(setq org-export-with-section-numbers nil)"

Here is document of it:

org-export-with-section-numbers is a variable defined in `ox.el'.
Its value is t

Documentation:
Non-nil means add section numbers to headlines when exporting.

When set to an integer n, numbering will only happen for
headlines whose relative level is higher or equal to n.

This option can also be set with the OPTIONS keyword,
e.g. "num:t".

You can customize this variable.