# Org HTML exporter: do not use section numbers in links?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

When linking to a heading containing `<<foo>>` using the syntax `[[foo]]`, `M-x org-html-export-to-html` generates a link using section number as the link text: `<a href="#org6bfafed">2.1.4</a>`.

[image]

Is it possible to configure the exporter such that instead of "2.1.4" it uses "foo" as the link text?

(I know I can also achieve this *laboriously* by rewriting all links to be of the form `[[foo][foo]]` - but that's obviously not the ideal solution).

Answer (score 1):

I found a different way of achieving this: **disable section numbering entirely** using `#+OPTIONS: num:nil` (see [How to eliminate the html headline number?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17869/how-to-eliminate-the-html-headline-number)) which has the effect of forcing the exporter to use link text as-is.

Note:

- When using `org-html-export-to-html` I get `No description for this link`
- However, this is not the case with `org-pandoc-export-to-html5-and-open`

But then the Pandoc exporter is not as rich as the original exporter. So this solution is not ideal.